# i need to change a div when we click on pagination ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, pagination

```
class ProductTheme extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { activePage : 1 , formValues: {}, totalPages:10}

    }
    render(){
    const {handleSubmit} = this.props; 
    const page = this.state.totalPages;
        return( 
            <div><ThemesNavBar/>
            <div className="container" id="PTConatiner">
            <h2>Product Explainer Information</h2>
      <div className = "container">
       <form className="form-inline" onSubmit = {handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
      <Field label="Meet" value={this.state.formValues["cname"]} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'svgObject','cname', 'cprofession')} name="cname" component={ this.renderField}/>
      <Field label="He's" value={this.state.formValues["cprofession"]} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'svgObject','cname', 'cprofession')} name="cprofession" component={ this.renderField}/>
      </form>
      </div>
      <object type="image/svg+xml" ref="svgObject" data={require("./images/svg files/Scene_01.svg")} id='svgObject' ></object>
      <div id="screenPage02">
      <Field label="He's Struggling To" value={this.state.formValues["struggling"]} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} name="struggling" component={ this.renderField}/>
            <object type="image/svg+xml" ref="svgObject01" data={require("./images/svg files/Scene_02.svg")} id='svgObject01' ></object>
      </div>
        {divData.map((data)=>{
          console.log(data);
        })}
             <Pagination
        prev
        next
        first
        last
        boundaryLinks
        items={page}
        maxButtons={2}
        activePage={this.state.activePage}
        onSelect={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}
      />
            </div></div>
            );
    };
};
```

Hi , when user clicks on a particular no in pagination it should change to the div which is related to it how to do it with React ? i had a look at some NPM modules but those are not working for me ?

Comment: why are you changing the div? why cant you change the content of the current div?

Comment: that can be done with the help of state but the thing is there isn't any module like there are some functions in jQuery

Comment: What's your or some lib's `Pagination` implementation? Feels like `activePage` or `onSelect` would give you the ability to update

Comment: that's from react-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I guess you approach is not correct you must not load a new component or div each time , either you can go for changing div content as page changes only content must change that you can do with keeping data in `state` and load limited data what required for first page , once page changes , change div with that slot of data.

Comment: you can refer this  [link](https://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/pEYPbY)

Answer (score 0):

You should store your curent page data in *component state* or in *Redux store*.

Your source code is too short to understand your case. I don't know which *Pagination* library you use.

If you want similar solution with source check:
[Demo](https://tranzystor.github.io/redux-cached-pagination/#/)

[Github](https://github.com/Tranzystor/redux-cached-pagination)